# Eclipse 3.7 line wrap early on comments

Tags: eclipse, word-wrap

I'm running the indigo release on Windows Vista.
I have set both the print margin in General -> Editors -> Text Editors and the maximum line width in Java -> Code Style -> Formatter to 100 characters, yet it is still determined to wrap my comments at column 80.

For example, when this is typed at the top of my file:
(longest lines are 90 and 94 characters respectively)

```
// This comment is over 80 characters long, but it is in no way over 100 characters long.  
/*  
 * The same problem occurs in block comments as well. True, neither problem is code breaking,  
 * but it certainly is annoying all the same.  
 */
```

It is formatted to:
(lines are 73 and 79 characters respectively)

```
// This comment is over 80 characters long, but it is in no way over 100  
// characters long.  
/*  
 * The same problem occurs in block comments as well. True, neither problem is  
 * code breaking,  
 * but it certainly is annoying all the same.  
 */
```

I have tried restarting Java and have hit every "apply" button I can find, but to no avail. It does not appear to be listed as a known issue in the release notes. Is there something I'm missing? Something simple perhaps?

Answer (score 2):

At least on Eclipse Helios (3.6), there's a separate "Comments"-tab on the Formatter-settings, which has its own "Maximum line width for comments"-setting.

Comment: There doesn't a separate line width setting in the Comments tab in 3.7, or at least I don't see it. Thanks anyway.